# Is there a way to know which sublayout is loaded in a Jekyll layout

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the following layout files for my Jekyll project :

```
_layouts
  main.html
  post.html
```

In all cases, I load the `main.html` layout. If the requested page is a post, I nest the `post.html` layout inside the main one using `{{ content }}`.

Is it possible to know (from the main layout) if a sublayout has been loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Front matter entry for that.

```
---
layout: post.html
sublayout = post.html
---
```

And in your page.html you can then check {{ page.sublayout }}. {{ page.layout itself }} will be main.html in the outer template.

Comment: This is exactly what I do for the moment, but I'm looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: There is no cleaner way. But somehow i suspect for page layout might be screwed. Why would you need to know the sublayout in the outer layout? the parent layout should be completely independent from the sub layout, otherwise something is not quite right to begin with.

Comment: I made a menu in the `main.html` layout. In this menu, I need to know whether in which page I am to do some simple effects (like changing background color of the specified menu item). In other cases (Home page, Contact page, etc...) I can rely on the page title, but for specific posts, the page title is useless. So I have to use an other information, like the used sublayout.

Comment: you can not use the sublayout for that, since you might have two pages that use the same sublayout (you most definitely will have multiple pages that use the same sublayout, that's what layouts are for), so using an additional YAML front matter enty (e.g. `activeMenuItem: XXX`) is the cleanest way to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do it this way.